# How to center align my cards, grid with respect to strength image?

Tags: html, css

> I want to center align my grid with respect to the strength heading, currently my grid is indented towards left side. Now I want to align with respect to strength heading.

Considering that I am using flip cards for grid elements, so there alignment must not be disturbed in any case.

HTML that is presented is just the part of code ,considering I have 120 flip cards and each row must have 5 cards.The css attached is for flip cards and the grid that has been created

Also please indicate where I was doing mistake.

```css
.flip-card {
  border-style: hidden;
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.flip-card-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-card-front,
.flip-card-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip-card-front {
  background-color: #bbb;
  color: black;
}

.flip-card-back {
  background-color: #222e36ef;
  color: white;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  grid-gap: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 100%; text-align: center; padding: 5px 2px; clear: both;"><img alt="" src="img/heroes_thumbnail/heroes_thumbnail_large/strength.PNG" width="100" height="100" loading="lazy" />
  <h4>Strength</h4>
</div>
<div class="row">


  <!-- #str heroes -->
  <!-- #abaddon -->
  <div class="grid" style="align-self: center">
    <div class="flip-card">
      <div class="flip-card-inner">
        <div class="flip-card-front">
          <img src="img/heroes_thumbnail/heroes_thumbnail_large/abaddon_lg.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:120px;height:120px;">
        </div>
        <div class="flip-card-back">
          </br>
          <p>WR : 50%</p>
          <p>PR : 50%</p>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- #alchemist -->
    <div class="flip-card">
      <div class="flip-card-inner">
        <div class="flip-card-front">
          <img src="img/heroes_thumbnail/heroes_thumbnail_large/alchemist_lg.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:120px;height:120px;">
        </div>
        <div class="flip-card-back">
          <h1>Win Rate</h1>
          <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
          <p>We love that guy</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- #axe -->
    <div class="flip-card">
      <div class="flip-card-inner">
        <div class="flip-card-front">
          <img src="img/heroes_thumbnail/heroes_thumbnail_large/axe_lg.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:120px;height:120px;">
        </div>
        <div class="flip-card-back">
          <h1>Win Rate</h1>
          <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
          <p>We love that guy</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>



    <!-- #beastm -->
    <div class="flip-card">
      <div class="flip-card-inner">
        <div class="flip-card-front">
          <img src="img/heroes_thumbnail/heroes_thumbnail_large/beastmaster_lg.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:120px;height:120px;">
        </div>
        <div class="flip-card-back">
          <h1>Win Rate</h1>
          <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
          <p>We love that guy</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>



    <!-- #brewm -->
    <div class="flip-card">
      <div class="flip-card-inner">
        <div class="flip-card-front">
          <img src="img/heroes_thumbnail/heroes_thumbnail_large/brewmaster_lg.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:120px;height:120px;">
        </div>
        <div class="flip-card-back">
          <h1>Win Rate</h1>
          <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
          <p>We love that guy</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- #bb -->
    <div class="flip-card">
      <div class="flip-card-inner">
        <div class="flip-card-front">
          <img src="img/heroes_thumbnail/heroes_thumbnail_large/bristleback_lg.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:120px;height:120px;">
        </div>
        <div class="flip-card-back">
          <h1>Win Rate</h1>
          <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
          <p>We love that guy</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Move the (Div with h4-Strength) into the (Div with class="grid")

If you do that you need to add to style 'grid-area: 1 / 1 / 1 / 7',
So the Div with the h4 will catch the whole first row.

---

I must to say that its seems only in tiny screen, and I will recomend to you for a responsive way to do that.
You just need to stay with your code and replace the

grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);

To:

grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill,minmax(170px,1fr));

And that will make the grid responsive.

```css
.flip-card {
  border-style: hidden;
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.flip-card-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-card-front,
.flip-card-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip-card-front {
  background-color: #bbb;
  color: black;
}

.flip-card-back {
  background-color: #222e36ef;
  color: white;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  grid-gap: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">


  <!-- #str heroes -->
  <!-- #abaddon -->
  <div class="grid" style="align-self: center">
  <div style="width: 100%; text-align: center; padding: 5px 2px; clear: both; grid-area: 1 / 1 / 1 / 7;"><img alt="" src="img/heroes_thumbnail/heroes_thumbnail_large/strength.PNG" width="100" height="100" loading="lazy" />
  <h4>Strength</h4>
</div>
    <div class="flip-card">
      <div class="flip-card-inner">
        <div class="flip-card-front">
          <img src="img/heroes_thumbnail/heroes_thumbnail_large/abaddon_lg.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:120px;height:120px;">
        </div>
        <div class="flip-card-back">
          </br>
          <p>WR : 50%</p>
          <p>PR : 50%</p>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- #alchemist -->
    <div class="flip-card">
      <div class="flip-card-inner">
        <div class="flip-card-front">
          <img src="img/heroes_thumbnail/heroes_thumbnail_large/alchemist_lg.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:120px;height:120px;">
        </div>
        <div class="flip-card-back">
          <h1>Win Rate</h1>
          <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
          <p>We love that guy</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- #axe -->
    <div class="flip-card">
      <div class="flip-card-inner">
        <div class="flip-card-front">
          <img src="img/heroes_thumbnail/heroes_thumbnail_large/axe_lg.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:120px;height:120px;">
        </div>
        <div class="flip-card-back">
          <h1>Win Rate</h1>
          <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
          <p>We love that guy</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>



    <!-- #beastm -->
    <div class="flip-card">
      <div class="flip-card-inner">
        <div class="flip-card-front">
          <img src="img/heroes_thumbnail/heroes_thumbnail_large/beastmaster_lg.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:120px;height:120px;">
        </div>
        <div class="flip-card-back">
          <h1>Win Rate</h1>
          <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
          <p>We love that guy</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>



    <!-- #brewm -->
    <div class="flip-card">
      <div class="flip-card-inner">
        <div class="flip-card-front">
          <img src="img/heroes_thumbnail/heroes_thumbnail_large/brewmaster_lg.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:120px;height:120px;">
        </div>
        <div class="flip-card-back">
          <h1>Win Rate</h1>
          <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
          <p>We love that guy</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- #bb -->
    <div class="flip-card">
      <div class="flip-card-inner">
        <div class="flip-card-front">
          <img src="img/heroes_thumbnail/heroes_thumbnail_large/bristleback_lg.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:120px;height:120px;">
        </div>
        <div class="flip-card-back">
          <h1>Win Rate</h1>
          <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
          <p>We love that guy</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto; Doesn't this make responsive grid ? but you have helped me alot

Comment: I don't think, you can try it and also try the grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill,minmax(170px,1fr));
I was glad to helpץ

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want the top left corner of your grid to start right under the begining of your heading.
So why not make your heading the first row of your grid :`grid-column : 1 / span 5; grid-row : 1 / span 1;`
Then you can just align your grid (and header) as you want.